# Why PreferenceActivity throws UnsupportedEncodingException?

Tags: android

I'm trying to add settings to my application using PreferenceActivity (I'm targeting API level 8), I started with only one checkbox:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:key="pref_fps"
        android:title="FPS"
        android:defaultValue="false" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

My PreferenceActivity subclass only defines one "onCreate" method:

```
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
}
```

Everything seemed to be working fine at first, but I noticed that preferences were lost after an application restart. Looking at the logs, it seems the preferences can't be saved to disk. Every time I click on the checkbox in the PreferenceActivity, I'm getting this exception:

```
W/ApplicationContext( 9542): writeFileLocked: Got exception:
W/ApplicationContext( 9542): java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: utf-8
W/ApplicationContext( 9542):    at com.android.internal.util.FastXmlSerializer.setOutput(FastXmlSerializer.java:297)
W/ApplicationContext( 9542):    at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.writeMapXml(XmlUtils.java:181)
W/ApplicationContext( 9542):    at android.app.ContextImpl$SharedPreferencesImpl.writeFileLocked(ContextImpl.java:2928)
W/ApplicationContext( 9542):    at android.app.ContextImpl$SharedPreferencesImpl.access$300(ContextImpl.java:2676)
W/ApplicationContext( 9542):    at android.app.ContextImpl$SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.commit(ContextImpl.java:2861)
W/ApplicationContext( 9542):    at android.preference.Preference.tryCommit(Preference.java:1198)
W/ApplicationContext( 9542):    at android.preference.Preference.persistBoolean(Preference.java:1403)
W/ApplicationContext( 9542):    at android.preference.CheckBoxPreference.setChecked(CheckBoxPreference.java:154)
W/ApplicationContext( 9542):    at android.preference.CheckBoxPreference.onClick(CheckBoxPreference.java:143)
W/ApplicationContext( 9542):    at android.preference.Preference.performClick(Preference.java:810)
W/ApplicationContext( 9542):    at android.preference.PreferenceScreen.onItemClick(PreferenceScreen.java:198)
W/ApplicationContext( 9542):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
W/ApplicationContext( 9542):    at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3382)
W/ApplicationContext( 9542):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1696)
W/ApplicationContext( 9542):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
W/ApplicationContext( 9542):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
W/ApplicationContext( 9542):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
W/ApplicationContext( 9542):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
W/ApplicationContext( 9542):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
W/ApplicationContext( 9542):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
W/ApplicationContext( 9542):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
W/ApplicationContext( 9542):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
W/ApplicationContext( 9542):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/ApplicationContext( 9542): Caused by: java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException: The unsupported charset name is "utf-8".
W/ApplicationContext( 9542):    at java.nio.charset.Charset.forName(Charset.java:544)
W/ApplicationContext( 9542):    at com.android.internal.util.FastXmlSerializer.setOutput(FastXmlSerializer.java:292)
W/ApplicationContext( 9542):    ... 22 more
```

Behavior is the same on the emulator and on a real device.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you try to Clean your project and re-build, than uninstall your app and re-install it to check whether it can be reproduced？

Comment: Yeah, just to make sure, I just uninstalled the application and did a new clean build, but it's still the same.

Comment: You said you get this exception when you click on checkbox. Could you paste the checkbox listener too? the pref xml has no problem. utf-8 should be supported..

Comment: I haven't set any listener, the events are handled internally by PreferenceActivity (well, if I understand correctly...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After spending some more time debugging my application, I finally found the problem: I'm using a native library and this library is doing a `mmap` to a fixed memory location at `0x80000000`.

Doing `mmap` at fixed locations is not such good idea. In our case, it seems to overwrite the available charsets of the application. Which is why `PreferenceActivity` was not able to save a file to disk.